# Remote delay Multiplier repeat potentiometer

Tags: audio

ADA 2FX.  I'm trying to remote the Multiplier (delay time) to a foot pedal.  I have removed the potentiometer from the unit and put it in a volume pedal.  It's wired as a variable resistor exactly as it is when it was in the unit.

Here's the really weird part.  If I use a 15' high quality (Mogami) low capacitance microphone cable to the pot, the repeats are very distorted. This occurs whether the shield is grounded on both ends, either end, or completely floated.  I have tried buffering the signal with a high quality buffer and the result is the same in all the configurations previously mentioned.

However, when using a common 15' zip (lamp) cord, it works perfectly.  No distortion in the repeats.

The pot in question is P11 in the lower left corner.  Can anyone explain this phenomenon?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a classic oscillator where C123 (51pF) is charged and discharged. The pot sets charge/discharge time, thus period, thus sets the frequency.

The shielded cable has too much capacitance, probably more than C123. It's in parallel with the pot, so it perturbs the frequency.

A solution would be to remote the whole oscillator instead.

Have a cable with VCC, GND, and clock. Then a small PCB with the same circuit as in your schematic, a local decoupling (like 10µF aluminium + 100nF ceramic)... If you use jack connectors, a current limit resistor in VCC on the powered side would be a plus as the pins short against each other during insertion.

How to mod your board...

You could use a jack connector with a switch that detects insertion, like headphone jacks, here's [an example](https://www.mouser.fr/ProductDetail/CUI-Devices/SJ-63013G?qs=hWgE7mdIu5S69fEK1bqK5w%3D%3D):

[image]

9,8,4 are the usual jack contacts. When one is inserted, the contact between 2 and 3 breaks.

[image]

So the point is to drill a hole in your effects rack and put a female jack, probably on the back panel. The existing circuit still works with the pot on the front panel. When no male jack is inserted, the clock from this circuit goes through the contact in the female jack connector and the effect works as usual.

When a jack is inserted, the contact breaks and the clock is now taken from the tip of the jack instead.

The rest of the components (diodes, caps, resistors...) are for ESD protection, short protection, etc. It would be best to solder D7 on the jack connector so it shorts incoming ESD to the chassis directly.

Comment: Hi Bob,  Great idea!  U50 is a CD4049BE which has 6 inverting buffers/converters.  Since I would only need two for this project, can you recommend an equivalent IC with less than 16 pins?  Or, should I just stick with the 4049 to be sure it's the same circuit? Very new at this.  Thanks for your understanding and, thanks for answering my question.  Very much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, there are chips with 2 gates but they're all surface mount. Unused gates in the 6 gate chip should have their inputs grounded otherwise they act as antennas and pick up noise or oscillate. I've added some ideas to the answer.

Comment: Wow!  That's beautiful and above and beyond the call of duty.  Since I have several of these to do, I'll do the rest this way.  In the meantime, I removed all the components from the PCB and rebuilt the oscillator on a pad board and mounted it in the foot pedal.  Works nicely as originally described.  Worked better with isolated jacks.  Thanks Bob!!!

Comment: Nice! Well done!